# Search record from one table in other table and receive info about this

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In T1 I have a 50 ID'ss. I'm trying to find which ones are in T2. And add row name "test" next to ID with info about occurrence in T2. But when I put my code I receive only ID's which are included in T2. What I`m doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS test
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Just do `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id) then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from t1;
```

Note that `select distinct` is not needed.  That construct just slows down queries, if it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS test
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join to get the unmatched rows as well.

```
select t1.id 
, case when t2.id is null then 0 else 1 end as test
from t1 
left outer join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```